# How can I analyze why gettext doesn't work?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I am currently trying to use gettext with PHP and poedit. I wrote the following test.php file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED | -1);
bindtextdomain('messages', './i18n/');
textdomain('messages');
setlocale(LC_ALL, $_GET['l']);
putenv("LANG=".$_GET['l']);

echo _('test :-(');

?>
```

and this is my messages.po:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Community Chess\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-10-07 18:34+0100\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: Martin Thom <info@martin-thoma.de>\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: /var/www/community-chess\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: test.php:8
msgid "test :-("
msgstr "Juhu :-)"

#~ msgid "test"
#~ msgstr "Juhu!"
```

My directory structure is

```
community-chess
    test.php
    i18n
        de_DE
            LC_MESSAGES
                messages.po
                messages.mo
```

As soon as I look at http://localhost/community-chess/test.php?l=de_DE I get "test :-("

I have generated the locale with

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE
```

and checked with

```
locale -a
```

Why doesn't it work? How can I get some feedback from gettext?

Comment: did you enable php_gettext in php.ini?

Comment: according to phpinfo(): "GetText Support enabled"

Comment: Instead of `setlocale()` try `putenv("LANG=")` and the others.

Comment: I tried only putenv and putenv with setlocale. Both didn't work.

Comment: Gettext sucks for this exact reason. I would consider using [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) instead. It can deal with .mo/.po files

Comment: Simply restarting Apache2 did the trick (`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`). I came to the idea, as `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE')); ` printed `bool(false)`. It should print `string(5) "de_DE"`. Nether the less, I would like to know if I can get some feedback from gettext.

Comment: Probably no but you can use "strace" just as I did. 
I discovered that locale you set must exist in the system. I tried to set "pl_PL" but it's not installed in my ArchLinux so I had to choose "pl_PL.UTF-8".

Comment: In my experience, gettext can fail to work in many imaginative ways. You should always explain what's the exact problem: no translations at all, always the same language, missing words...

Answer (score 1):

This is what work for me on CE ZendServer on linux and Apache server on NetBsd

File "message.po" is generated from the root of application:

```
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-04-30 19:38+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-04-12 14:00+0000\n"
"Last-Translator: gin(e) <ginex@posta.indivia.net>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: eo\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: include/apteryx_text.php:3
msgid "email:"
msgstr "Retpoŝtadreso:"
```

This is the new tree-directory:

```
res/locale/
    de_DE/
       LC_MESSAGES/
            messages.mo
    eo_EO/
       LC_MESSAGES/
            messages.mo
    eo->eo_EO (symlink)
```

I must add the "eo" symlink because the only three esperanto locales on my system supported are:

```
eo
eo.iso88593
eo.utf8
```

compiled whit:

```
sudo locale-gen eo
sudo locale-gen eo.iso88593
sudo locale-gen eo.utf8
sudo update-locale
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and at the moment my locale.php code is:

```
$charset="UTF-8";
$gettext_domain="messages";
$locale_dir="res/locale";
putenv("LC_ALL=$lang");
$l=split("_",$lang);
/* not in all system and not all locales got the classic name this stupid method try to solve it*/
if(! setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.".".$charset)) 
  if(! setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang)) 
    if(! setlocale(LC_ALL,$l[0].".".$charset))  
        setlocale(LC_ALL,$l[0]);

bindtextdomain($gettext_domain, "res/locale");
textdomain($gettext_domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($gettext_domain, $charset);
```

because whitout it gettext doesn't work. I think that the locale directory must have the same name of the language setted whit setlocale. Another things is to test every function called what return. Them must never return NULL or FALSE. You can do that in simple way:

```
var_dump(bindtextdomain($gettext_domain, "res/locale"));
var_dump(textdomain($gettext_domain)); 
..and so on..
```

The last but not the list, remember to set the right apache permission to all .mo file, to restart your apache server and verify by phpinfo() that "GetText Support" is "enabled".

Answer (score 1):

When I restart nginx through the cmd "/path/to/nginx -s reload",it dosen't work,but after I restart php-fpm with the cmd "/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart",it worked!
Hope my experience will be helpful to someone with the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you missed it, the OP said in his comments above that he fixed this by simply restarting Apache. I was having troubles with `_()` just not working. The locale was setting fine, `bindtextdomain` and `textdomain` were returning the correct values, but it just wasn't working. **I restarted Apache and it worked.**